# Sitemap confusion on Google Console: One website accessible by two URLs

Tags: google, google-search-console, sitemap, ecommerce

I am a novice when it comes to websites, the language and technical side.  Excuse if this sounds elementary.

If you have one website accessible by two URLs, do I need to add a sitemap for each one?  When I sign on to Google Console - I see both URLs and click between the two. Both lead to my new Shopify store but only one has the sitemap.

I recently got rid of my WordPress site and moved URL to Shopify through a secured network since it is now e-commerce - hence the `https`.  Shopify Staff helped me set it up and told me where to paste the site map.  I don't know if they knew I had two URLs in Console or even if it matters.  I just want to make sure I am set up in the best way for traffic and indexing.

I became confused when I looked at Google Console  Performance for both and noticed the URL with no site map is getting more traffic/performance than the one with the site map.

Below are the details...

The first site has the sitemap but I noticed less performance:

TOTAL CLICKS 27
TOTAL IMPRESSIONS 466

The second site DOES NOT have a site map but more traffic - I got this secured network when I signed on when Shopify since it is e-commerce:

TOTAL CLICKS 257
TOTAL IMPRESSIONS 14.2K

Which ever URL you enter will take you to the same secured site.  I just want to know if I should move the sitemap, or just leave well enough alone and be happy?

Comment: Are you talking about a site using http and a site using https. I suspect Shopify will be redirecting http to https meaning that Google will send little to no traffic to the http variant. Submit your sitemap to the https oner.

Comment: Looks like the editor removed my links that is why it might be confusing.  The first site which is HTTP has the sitemap but I noticed less performance:
TOTAL CLICKS 27 TOTAL IMPRESSIONS 466

The second site HTTPS - DOES NOT have a site map but more traffic - I got this secured network when I signed on when Shopify since it is e-commerce:

TOTAL CLICKS 257 TOTAL IMPRESSIONS 14.2K

So if I add the sitemap to HTTPS - do I need to delete it from the other - or can you have both.  Just wondering if it is dangerous to delete a site map once it is indexed.

Comment: Tony I studied this more on Google Console and it does appear that all the traffic from HTTP is being redirected to my HTTPS now even though the sitemap is on the HTTP url.    I guess I could leave well enough alone unless you think it is important for the sitemap to be on the HTTPS one now.

Comment: Add the sitemap to the https property and focus on that one for your traffic. Keep the http property as is, Google may alert you if there is an issue on that side.